# Send NSB message from async action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, nservicebus

I have read the following article, but it doesn't seem to explain how to do this **without** using async controller - which is more old school. (hence tedious)

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/using-nservicebus-with-asp.net-mvc

Is there an up to date example that shows request/response NSB messaging with the new .NET 4.5 async action? Especially the web api flavor

```
public async Task<ExtDto> PostAction() {
    var command = new MyCmd();
    ExtDto response;
    var res = _bus.Send(command)
    //*** What do I need here, so I can handle NServiceBus response ***//
    //*** and map that to variable "response"                       ***//
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the doco with an example how to use the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern from NServiceBus see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/using-nservicebus-with-asp.net-mvc#asynchronous-message-sending-sendasync-controller.

Hope the doco makes sense now ?